# SimpleXML content:encoded node missing

Tags: xml, simplexml

I'm trying to get the RSS feed from a WordPress.com blog with SimpleXML, but the content node is missing.

Here's my code:

```
$feed = file_get_contents('http://blog.wordpress.com/category/category-name/feed');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
var_dump($xml);
```

On the URL itself, there is a content:encoded. Also var_dump($feed) shows the content. But somehow after simplexml, the content node is missing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the XML that you're reading in?

Comment: I actually found another way, that works with WP: http://bavotasan.com/2010/display-rss-feed-with-php/

Comment: I'd still be interested in knowing why is this is happening and how to prevent it...